# Display special non-English characters

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, text, character-encoding, special-characters

Chrome on Ubuntu doesn't display special characters in words like Bo͞oyä when displaying. It works in Windows and Android. Also when typing the characters they look good, but not when displaying. Right now as I am typing this question, it shows right in the text-area but not in the preview below. Why? All works fine on Firefox on Ubuntu.

I asked this on Ubuntu forum but they pointed out that the problem was with Chrome. They are right. So where to post if not here?

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Older browsers may not support all the HTML5 entities in the table below.
Chrome has good support. But (currently) only IE 11+ and Firefox 35+ support all the entities.

http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp